# Make PDF viewable online in the browser

Tags: pdf, jekyll

Note: Before asking i searched some on embedding but couldn't get exactly what i wanted.

I have a resume file in the **pdf** format that i would like to display in my website without storing anywhere like google or other but on my own. I have static website ***[which i made using Jekyll]*** lets say **https://www.example.com** and what i actually need is to display my resume accessible in the following link **https://www.example.com/resume**

Some of them have long permalinks and i actually hate them. (Just saying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the PDF into the website's `/` or `assets/` directory.

To make a link for HTML:

```
<a href="<PATH>/cv.pdf">CV</a>
```

To make a link for Markdown:

```
[CV](<PATH>/cv.pdf)
```

Comment: This will automatically download the pdf when someone clicks on the CV option. What I need is to display that pdf in the link when clicked in the browser.

Comment: That's strange, this is supposed to work. I'm guessing the browser you're using automatically downloads the PDF rather than views it. Check out [this Chrome help guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en), it may help.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome, this has been [around for a long time](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333) and plagues webdevs to [this day](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333#c216). There seem to be no plans to change that anytime soon because that's just the way it was built. Chrome behaves slightly different when not online, so offline/local-testing will not always produce expected result.

My answer to you, for this question, is a suggestion. In order to make it cross-browser compatible, your mode of implementation should be:

1. [Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) or,
2. [Lightbox](https://ahmednooor.github.io/halkaBox.js/)

Whether or not you are using a [SSG](https://gist.github.com/dypsilon/4552696) should not matter here. Look for a bootstrap or material implementation.

> On the client-side, it is possible with [extension](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gRyGoOE0Fhs). I reckon this isn't helpful to you; but I'm including this information for future readers.